# ORA-29283: invalid file operation when calling utl_file.fopen on Windows server 2016

Tags: windows, oracle12c, file-permissions, windows-server-2016

Most of the answers I've seen are for Linux. Windows permissions have an element of black magic about them. This is Windows Server 2016.

I created the `d:\data\transfer\sirius\` directory on the Oracle database server.

As `SYSDBA` I do the following:

```
create or replace directory SIRIUS_DIR as 'd:\data\transfer\sirius\';
grant read,write on directory SIRIUS_DIR to SIRIUS;
```

Then on another server, in a SQL*Plus session as the `SIRIUS` user, I run:

```
DECLARE     myFile utl_file.file_type;                                             
BEGIN
 myFile := utl_file.fopen('SIRIUS_DIR ', 'random.txt', 'w', 32000);
END;
/
```

Which gives:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 536
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 41
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 478
ORA-06512: at line 3
```

How to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. You need to grant full access to the **ORA_INSTALL** group to the directory in question on the database. According to the [Oracle configuration docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NTDBI/user_grps.htm#CIHEFHBG):

> The ORA_INSTALL group contains all the Oracle Home Users for all
> Oracle homes on the server.

Thanks to this [kindly blogger](https://paulzipblog.wordpress.com/2021/01/02/ora-29283-invalid-file-operation/) for his solution.

Answer (score 0):

ORA_INSTALL might work on Windows, but on Linux (Oracle linux 8.9) I had to chown the directory to oracle:oinstall. (or chmod it 777)

I'm aware this question was for Windows, but I googled for Linux and Google brought me here